# Is there any WYSIWYG html editor that automatically replace special characters with HTML Entities?

Tags: html, editor

I am looking for a **WYSIWYG** html editor that can automatically replace special characters with HTML Entities such as "&#number" in the source code. The feature has a good demonstration in these two site

1. https://mothereff.in/html-entities
2. http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html

I tried several HTML editors such as "seamonkey composer","wizHTMLeditor"... They are all failed my requiement.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.tinymce.com/. It replaces `&` with `&amp;`, so I think the other special character to. All you need to get started:

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
```

Thats all you need

Comment: But it can't replace chinese characters as far as I know